# Amazon Alexa doesn't open the skill developed by me on alexa device but its visible in alexa app in dev tab

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Amazon Alexa doesn't open the skill developed by me( on the device)

my developed skill is in dev tab of alexa app. But when I am trying to access it from device its not working. please tell me all the possible test or solution which i can perform to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your skill is not yet certified, check that your device is logged in to the same Amazon account you are using for development.